# Jquery ajax cross domain policy issue for consuming spring 3.0 rest webservice

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-services, spring, rest

We have implemented webservice which generates xml response.

I am facing issue while invoking it through the jquery ajax.

If I put same file within the same container I am getting a proper response.
This is because of the cross domain policy.

Please suggest me how to use cross domain policy in jquery ajax?

I am using tomcat as a webserver. All webservices are deployed on this server.

Below is the code.

```
function doajaxcall() 
{
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:8080/mobile-services/rest/languages/",
    type: "GET",
    processdata: true,
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json;",
    beforeSend: function () { },
    headers : 
    {
        "Content-Type"  : "application/json",
        "Accept" : "application/json",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"http://192.168.0.1:8080/"
    },
    success: function (data) 
    {          
        alert('Data..'+data);
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) 
    {
        try 
        {
            alert(JSON.stringify(XMLHttpRequest) + "\n" + textStatus + "\n" + errorThrown);
        }
        catch (ex) { alert("Exception occured.. "); }
        finally { }
    }
});
```

}

If i run this code from the same container in header i am getting 
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"http://192.168.0.1:8080/" in header.

If i run it outside of the container i am getting

"Access-Control-Allow-Origin":null

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JSONP (JSON with padding) as the dataType for cross-domain requests.

For example:

```
(function($) {
var url = 'http://localhost:8080/mobile-services/rest/languages/test.json?callback=?';

  $.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   url: url,
   async: false,
   jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
   contentType: "application/json",
   dataType: 'jsonp',
   success: function(json) {

   //your code
    },
 error: function(e) {
   console.log(e.message);
 }
 });
 })(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks Ravi, i am getting error message "xml document cannot be whole the program ".

Comment: Take a look at this answer on how to handle xml data with jsonp [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771521/xml-cannot-be-the-whole-program)

Comment: Thanks Ravi issue has been fixed.

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted if it has solved your issue. See this for more info http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Hi Ravi, This helped me a lot. I have implemented customized filter which converts spring json response to jsonp. Also configured CORS filter on server side.

Answer (score 2):

To fix this issue.
I have added cors-filter-1.3.1.jar to webservices/web-inf/lib. directory.

below is the web.xml file configuration to enable cross domain access for tomcat.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Changed the response type of spring 3.0 webservices from xml to JSON.
I am using following code snippet to read JSON data from the webservice.

```
$.getJSON('http://localhost:8080/mobile-services/rest/languages/',
function(data) 
{
    $("#lang_1").html(data.languages[0].language);
    $("#lang_2").html(data.languages[1].language);
    $("#lang_3").html(data.languages[2].language); 
});
```