# jQuery error "missing ; (semicolon) before statement <script type="text/javascript">\n " after Ajax request. Any idea?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am stuck with my Rails application where I use JQuery to post/get ajax requests and I have this following error (found by using Firebug).

```
missing ; before statement 

<script type="text/javascript">\n
```

I am using the JQuery ajax method to post like this:

```
function day_on_change() {    
     jQuery.post( "/times/add"+ "?day_id=" + $('#day_id').val() + "&pool_id=" + $('#pool_id').val() ,null, function(data) {
       $('#container').html(data);
     }, "script");
}
```

The function 'day_on_change' is called when a select dropdown menu is changed. It posts to 'times/add' with ajax and the response data is replaced in the Div with id 'container'.

The response data is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  DD_roundies.addRule('#normal_header_2', '5px 5px 0 0');
  DD_roundies.addRule('#normal_footer', '0 0 5px 5px');

</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {

  //more js code here
});
</script>
<!-- Some HTML here too -->
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: What code is before this? It's possible it didn't end with a `;`.

Comment: When you say "after AJAX request", do you mean after your code where you make the request, or after the response has been received. Your AJAX is apparently returning a script, so there could be an error in that script if the Firebug message is coming after the response.

Comment: I just updated the question to give you more info. @patrick, Yes the reponse data contains some javascripts along with html (see the code). But it all seems valid and correct to me.

Thanks.

Comment: Again, is the error happening *before* the AJAX request, or *after* the response is received?

Comment: //more js code here - may be the error is here? 
have you tried other developer tools i.e. in Chrome or IE - they can give you additional information.

Comment: @patrick, it was happening after the response is received. @dmitko the js there is perfectly fine. I found out the problem. Please see my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After raging hours of debugging and trying to solve the problem, I finally found out what's causing the problem. Please let me explain

From Rails app, when I call ajax requests like

```
jQuery.post( "/times/add"+ "?day_id=" + $('#day_id').val() + "&pool_id=" + $('#pool_id').val() ,null, function(data) {
       $('#container').html(data);
     }, "script");
```

, it seems JQuery expects the response to be a "script" (since I uses 'script' option in the jQuery.post method). But in my controller of the Rails app, I was responding to that request as follows:

```
 respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :action => 'embed' }
      format.js { render :partial => 'embed_' + @size, :locals => {:timetable_entries => @timetable_entries} }
    end
```

I was responding the request with a partial which is just 'html.erb' file which has mixed codes including JS, HTML and Ruby. And after testing for some hours, I found out that I still have various kinds of error in the firebug even without the javascript in the response data. It gives me "XML cannot be the whole program" error when I have no js code in there. So after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371189/what-does-firebug-xml-cannot-be-the-whole-program-error-message-mean), I realize that I am returning the response data in wrong format.

So I changed my controller to respond like this.

```
 respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :action => 'embed' }
      format.js
    end
```

which will basically expect 'add.js' file to process the javascripts. So I created the add.js and in there I put this.

```
$("#container").html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'embed_' + @size, :locals => {:timetable_entries => @timetable_entries}) %>");
```

Then only I see no more errors in the browser. I hope this will save hours of frustrations for those who have same problem like me.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Run your code through JSLint

(Note: JSLint will hurt your feelings)

Comment: It's a great tool, thanks. But doesn't seem to help much here with ajax requests from Rails app, unfortunately.