# XML can't be the whole program

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I include the following js file (with jquery in it), I get the error in Firebug "XML can't be the whole program"

JS file include reference:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/scriptname.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

JS file contents:

```
$("[id*='txtAddress1S']")
  .blur(function(){
   $("[id*='txtAddress1S']")
      .val().match(
          /\b[p]*(ost)*\.*\s*[o|0]*(ffice)*\.*\s*b[o|0]x\b/i)&&
         (alert("Packages are not deliverable to a Post Office Box.
         \nPlease provide a different shipping address."),
    $("[id*='txtAddress1S']").focus())
  });
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's one weird Firebug error.

Comment: The js file doesn't contain `script` tags, right?

Comment: Does your page also have jquery*.js or jquery*min.js?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does Firebug "XML cannot be the whole program" error message mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371189/what-does-firebug-xml-cannot-be-the-whole-program-error-message-mean)

Comment: But check the error console first. If there an error message, it isn't a bug from firebug.
Btw what does the path reference '~' mean?

Comment: @reporter: On Linux (and Mac OS) systems, ~ is your home directory.

Comment: it is an invalid path reference.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It might be that your script `src` attribute is not properly understood with the `~` and being parsed as an empty `<script>` tag instead.  Use the full path to the javascript file, or a path relative to the page it's loading on:

```
<script src="/full/path/to/Scripts/scriptname.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../relative/to/Scripts/scriptname.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: This was it.  Firefox didn't like the ~ in my relative path.

Answer (score 4):

For some reason, your script file is being treated by Firefox as an XML file.  My guess is that you have included `script` tags in your Javascript file.  E.g.

```
<script>
    $("[id*='txtAddress1S']").blur(function(){$("[id*='txtAddress1S']").val().match(/\b[p]*(ost)*\.*\s*[o|0]*(ffice)*\.*\s*b[o|0]x\b/i)&&(alert("Packages are not deliverable to a Post Office Box.\nPlease provide a different shipping address."),$("[id*='txtAddress1S']").focus())});
</script>
```

You don't need `script` tags in an external JS file.

The equivalent error in Chrome is

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Answer (score 1):

I found another reason for`"XML can't be the whole program` in FF and `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` in Chrome. In my case, everything was failing with `ScriptResource.axd`.

The reason was that I'm serving some pages from https and I have a manager switching between http and https requests depending on what is currently required. Due to incorrect configuration the manager was serving ScriptResource.axd always over http, which caused errors  on https pages.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this same error today. In my case it was because I didn't use HTML codes for special characters in my URL while doing an AJAX request. For example...

Using **`&amp;`** instead of using **&**

Answer (score 0):

Shooting from the hip: I actually got this error because I added a wildcard mapping for aspnet_isapi.dll in my IIS 5.1 / WinXP (for some MVC related work). This means .js files got processed by IIS differently. Once I removed the mapping, the error you describe disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same error.  Make sure the javascript include file does not contain < script> tags.  Once those are pulled out of your include file, the error goes away (assuming that's all that is wrong).